# recover internal storage data from soft bricked phone (No custom recovery, USB Debugging option NOT turned ON)

Tags: cyanogenmod, data-recovery, boot-loop, stock-android, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I have an YU Yuphoria (5010) **running on stock rom cm12 which it came with** and was working perfectly until yesterday I rebooted the device. Now when it powers up it goes on a **boot loop**.

I have some photos of my newborn cousin in it which i really need.

My problems are as follows:

1. *USB debugging not enabled*. Which means my phone is not detected by adb and I can't mount or pull data from my phone through adb commands.
2. *No custom recovery* has been installed and the phone is not rooted. So no way to mount internal storage through CWM or TWRP as the don't exist.
3. *Fastboot works fine* but no option to access internal storage from it and unlocking bootloader will wipe all my data.

I tried all sorts of solutions but nothing worked because of problem 1 and 2. I really need those photos. Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: Raw idea: There seems to be [TWRP for this device](http://www.gizmoadvices.com/install-cwm-twrp-recovery-and-root-yu-yuphoria-yu5010/). Extract the `.img` file and ***boot*** (not flash!) it: `fastboot boot twrp.img`. That doesn't install it on the device, but uses the image as kind of "live disk" (it's gone when you reboot the device). TWRP comes with built-in ADB enabled, so while it's booted you'd have full root access to the device – if it works. Worth a try. Please report back whether you succeeded with that.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks but I am getting error saying: FAILED (remote: unlock device to use this command

Comment: I do have an option of adb sideload will that work?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback – that filled the one gap I had in my knowledge here (i.e. that `fastboot boot` also requires the device to be unlocked, which perfectly makes sense from a security standpoint). As unlocking would wipe the device, that's not a good option. I'm unaware of another way then – though it might be worth checking our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), as in that context the situation often is similar).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for your support but a miracle happened which I cannot figure out how. I decided to press wipe phone data from the stock recovery and it successfully booted up. Then i checked gallery and there was no photos in it which was obvious. then i plugged the phone to my computer and selected the file transfer mode on my phone. Then the internal memory shows up on my PC and I opened it up and saw the unexpected. All the files and folders including the app data was there as it is. I couldn't believe what i was seeing. It had all the photos that i wanted and some that i deleted long back.

Comment: Glad to read that, Hari! May I suggest you post that as answer (and accept that answer afterwards) – so other folks with a similar issue see there's a possible solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support but a miracle happened which I cannot figure out how. I decided to press wipe phone data from the stock recovery and it successfully booted up. Then I checked gallery and there was no photos in it which was obvious. then I plugged the phone to my computer and selected the file transfer mode on my phone. Then the internal memory shows up on my PC and I opened it up and saw the unexpected. All the files and folders including the app data was there as it is. I couldn't believe what I was seeing. It had all the photos that I wanted and some that I deleted long back.

Comment: Not working for me, all data lost, don't try this.

Comment: @preachers This wasn't a solution actually. This is what happened in my case, which might not work in yours.